# Creating a Symbolic Link to Access MySQL with Automatic Login

Tags: mysql, terminal, mamp, ln

I am looking for a simpler way to log in to `MySQL` through the terminal without having to input my username and password each time.

I am using `MAMP` and to access my databases, I just simply type `mysql` and it is accessed. To do that I just created a symbolic link `ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql /bin` but to be able to create databases and such I need to be logged in. I know I can do that by typing `mysql -uroot -ppassword` but that's a bit of a pain to type each time. Is their a way to use a symbolic link like to add attributes? Say like `ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot -ppassword`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlinks cannot contain command-line options.

You could instead place your credentials in an [option file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html).  If stored in a default location (such as `~/.my.cnf`), you won't even need to tell *`mysql`* to read it.

```
[client]
user=root
password=foobar
```

Beware, especially if doing this for the root user, that anyone with read access to your option file will be able to login as your user.

Comment: I'm using `MAMP`, do I edit it's own `my.cnf` file or do I create a new one elsewhere? If elsewhere, where so? Perhaps `/etc/my.cnf`?

Comment: @ChrisMellor: It depends whether you want the options to be system-wide or specific to your OS account (for the latter, the default location on Unix, Linux and Mac OS X was given in my answer: `~/.my.cnf`).  The manual page [Using Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/option-files.html) (also linked in my answer) covers all of this and more.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding the `my.cnf` file. I created a file inside `/etc` and it works great.